# Unable to Get Text From Text Recognition Using ML Kit Firebase

Tags: android, bitmap, firebase-mlkit

I'm using ML Kit Text Recognition in my android application. So the user writes something in the screen using Paint, then I save that image and process it using Firebase ML Kit Text Recognition. However, when the user clears the screen using Paint.clear() from the PaintView class which draws or writes to screen the ML Kit is still recognizing preview text written. what do I need to reset here. I'm using text to speech to speak written words.

```
paintView = (PaintView) findViewById(R.id.paintView);
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
paintView.init(metrics);

        speakTextButton = findViewById(R.id.button_speak);
        clearTextButton = findViewById(R.id.button_clear);

        Bitmap b = paintView.getDrawingCache();

        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            }
        });

        clearTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                paintView.clear();
            }
        });

        speakTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                paintView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); //saving image
                Bitmap bitmap = paintView.getDrawingCache();
                FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);

                //create detector
                FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
                        .getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();

                Task<FirebaseVisionText> result =
                        detector.processImage(image)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {
                                        extractText(firebaseVisionText);
                                    }
                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    }
                                });
            }
        });
    }

    public void extractText(FirebaseVisionText result) {
        resultText = result.getText();
        for (FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock block: result.getTextBlocks()) {
            for (FirebaseVisionText.Line line: block.getLines()) {
                if(line != null) {
                    Log.v("LINETEXT", line.getText());
                    Float lineConfidence = line.getConfidence();
                }
            }
        }
        startTextToSeech(resultText);

    }


    public void startTextToSeech(String resultText) {
        Log.v("QUOTE", resultText);
        textToSpeech.speak(resultText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement "StartTextToSpeech(resultText);" toward the bottom of your code has a typo in it. Instead of "StartTextToSpeech" it is "StartTextToSeech."

This could have some impact, and since it's a starting method it could be the whole problem.